# How Do I Correctly Hide Mouse Cursor On App Start?

Tags: uwp, c++-cx, directx-12

I want to hide the mouse cursor in my DX12 UWP C++/CX app:

`CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()->PointerCursor = nullptr;`

This hides the cursor after I use the touchpad/mouse to move it. It does not hide the cursor until this point. I've also tried the other suggestions of settings the position of the cursor afterwards:

`CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()->PointerPosition = Point(0, 0);`

This has no effect.

Everywhere I've looked says that setting the pointer to null will do the trick but it doesn't. What am I missing? This feels like a bug.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Tried in the methods:
`SetWindow`
`OnActivated`
`Run`

Edit 2:

```
auto applicationView = Windows::UI::ViewManagement::ApplicationView::GetForCurrentView();
while (!applicationView->TryEnterFullScreenMode()) {
    Sleep(10);
}

auto coreWindow = CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread();
coreWindow->PointerPosition = Point(coreWindow->Bounds.Width / 2, coreWindow->Bounds.Height / 2);
coreWindow->PointerCursor = nullptr;

uiThreadDispatcher->RunAsync(Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler([]() {
    auto coreWindow = CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread();
    coreWindow->PointerPosition = Point(coreWindow->Bounds.Width / 2, coreWindow->Bounds.Height / 2);
    coreWindow->PointerCursor = nullptr;
}));
```

It has happened, that the cursor sporadically disappears on App start, but this isn't repeatable. Regardless of where and when these methods are called, the only guaranteed way to get the cursor to disappear is when I move the cursor with the mouse or touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

> This hides the cursor after I use the touchpad/mouse to move it.

Set current `PointerCursor` as null only hide the cursor for current core window, it will not hidden the `PointerCursor` for whole system, for this scenario, you could launch the app with full screen and the cursor will hide automatically. And you could  try to set  `PointerPosition` in the core window center then set the PointerCursor as null, that could make sure the cursor in the window. Please note above method need to be called in the ui thrread.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sorry for the delay, was on holiday. I use the TryEnterFullScreenMode method and the pointer is still there. I additionally tried to set the pointerCursor to null using the CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()->Dispatcher. This again doesn't work until the mouse or touchpad are used.

Comment: Have you tried set PointerPosition  base on above setps?

Comment: I've updated the original question with code, showing what I am doing. Thanks!

Comment: Please set the PointerCursor  as null then move the PointerPosition  to the center of window

Comment: Still doesn't work... It only sporadically hides it. Whether I start from VS or from the UWP App itself, the only sure fire way is to move the mouse...

Comment: Where you call above code? I call above in the page's `OnNavigatedTo` method and it works expect .

Comment: I'm not using XAML, I'm using DirectX12... I call it in ```Run```.

Comment: And please note, if the cursor out of the window when app start, it will not work.